# Efficiently obtaining counts per group from multiple subsetting on a huge data.table

Tags: r, performance, filter, data.table

Is there a quick way to evaluate the *i* of a data.table[i,j] over multiple conditions? (My actual datatable has 2M rows. I want to do this with data.table operations, not loops or lapply).

For example, let's say I have:

```
require(data.table)
data = data.table(seq(0.25,10, by = 0.25), rep(c("a","b","c","d"),10))
filter = seq(0,10,by=1)
```

I now want to filter, say:

```
data[V1 > filter[4], .N, by=V2]
```

How can I evaluate this expression for all elements of filter?

- Note: I know I can loop through the data! This is not the answer I want!
- Edit: I want to do this internally in the data.table and not via lapply, as kindly pointed out.
- Edit 2:  The reason for this is that in the real problem, I have a dataset of 2 million rows that must be evaluated using a filter based on the same dataset at about 200 intervals. This must be repeated multiple times. So speed is of the essence.

Comment: What's your desired output? Are you against using `lapply` and getting a `list` of all of the resulting `data.table`s?

Comment: I am not too concerned about output. A matrix of output, by V2 would suffice. My main concern is avoiding the loop.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `lapply(filter, function(x)data[V1>x,.N,by=V2])` ?
`

Comment: When you say "avoiding the loop", are you specifically referring to an explicit `for` loop, or do you also include the `apply` family of functions there even though they are more optimized?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I meant to say that I want it evaluated via joins in the data.table framework.

Comment: The answer you "want" is highly subjective.  Unless this is homework, I strongly recommend you select a solution based on overall speed, then by robustness.

Comment: Ok. I will add some more explanation! And I would love to attend a place that gives data.table homework!

Comment: Quite interesting problem. Is your `filter` variable strictly integer?

Comment: @Arun, no, in fact it's a series of dates.

Comment: Err then give a reproducible example using dates, not integers.

Comment: I don't understand *"over multiple conditions"*. It's over a single condition, applied to ~200 subsets, right? It's not like you want to apply 200 different i-expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this'll work as good as it does here, but this is more or less the idea:

1) First, set the key on `V2` followed by `V1`:

```
setkey(data, V2, V1)
```

2) Next we add a couple of columns we'll use later:

```
data[, `:=`(id = 1:.N, N = .N), by=V2][, id := id[1L], by=list(V2,V1)]
```

The first is a running sequence from 1 to .N and second is the total count.

3) Here's where all the magic happens:

```
data[, V1.b := V1] ### this is necessary in 1.8.10 as V1 is not available in `j`
                   ### fixed in v1.8.11
ans <- data[CJ(x=unique(V2), y=filter), 
         list(start=id[1L], end=N[1L], 
         actual_num=V1.b[1L], close_match=y[1L]), 
       roll="nearest"]
```

So let's split this and understand. The first part, `CJ` creates the combinations for getting **all** results at once with a `join` (hence the `setkey` first). For each value in `i`, we use `roll="nearest"` to make sure we definitely get a match (the closest of the values available), and we note down `start`, `end` `V1` and `y` values for **that match**. So why do we need all these values? In particular why `V1` and `y`?

4) Now, from this result, `start` gives the first position where the match was and `end` always gives the total number of elements for that `V2`. However, there's one catch. If the number you're looking for counts where `V1 > 5` and the closest value in `V1` is `5.5` (> 5), then the `start` position is correct. However, if the closest value of `V1` is `4.5`, then we've to increment `start` by 1, because the match we have is the previous row.

A lot to take in... but doing it step by step should help. So, basically we do now:

```
ans[actual_num <= close_match, start := start+1L]
```

Exactly what I explained before (here, `V1` is `actual_num`).

5) Now, we can do `end-start+1` to get the total count:

```
ans[, tot_cnt := end-start+1L]
```

6) Cleaning up:

```
ans[, `:=`(start=NULL, end=NULL, close_match=NULL, actual_num=NULL)]
setnames(ans, 'V1', 'filter')
setkey(ans, filter)
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
setkey(data, V2, V1)
data[, `:=`(id = 1:.N, N = .N), by=V2][, id := id[1L], by=list(V2,V1)]
data[, V1.b := V1] ### required for 1.8.10, V1 is not available in `j`
                   ### fixed in 1.8.11
ans <- data[CJ(x=unique(V2), y=filter), 
            list(start=id[1L], end=N[1L], 
            actual_num=V1.b[1L], close_match=y[1L]), 
       roll="nearest"]
ans[actual_num <= close_match, start := start+1L]
ans[, tot_cnt := end-start+1L]
ans[, `:=`(start=NULL, end=NULL, close_match=NULL, actual_num=NULL)]
setnames(ans, 'V1', 'filter')
setkey(ans, filter)
```

Running this on @eddi's data takes about 2.4 seconds.

Comment: +1 because I think I understand the idea, but it's not working for me - the `ans <- ...` bit gives an error: `object V1 not found` (I'm running about a month old dt 1.8.11 on windows)

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks. Some scoping error that seems to have been fixed in 1.8.11. `j` dint see `V1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
data = data.table(val = seq(0.25,10, by = 0.25), grp = rep(c("a","b","c","d"),10))
filter = seq(0,10,by=1)

fl = data.table(filter, key = 'filter')

# to get strict inequality I subtracted a "small" number
# adjust it appropriately for your data
data[, max.filter := fl[J(val - 1e-7), .I, roll = Inf]$.I][,
       lapply(seq_along(filter), function(i) sum(max.filter >= i)), by = grp]
#   grp V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
#1:   a 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2   1   0
#2:   b 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2   1   0
#3:   c 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2   1   0
#4:   d 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2   1   0
```

Testing on data with 2M rows and 200 filter values it takes a bit over 5 seconds (and, to compare, naive `lapply` takes over a minute):

```
N = 2e6
data = data.table(val = runif(N, 1, N), grp = sample(letters, N, T))
filter = seq(0, N, by = N/200)

fl = data.table(filter, key = 'filter')
system.time(data[, max.filter := fl[J(val - 1e-7), .I, roll = Inf]$.I][, lapply(seq_along(filter), function(i) sum(max.filter >= i)), by = grp])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   5.24    0.00    5.41 

system.time(lapply(filter, function(x) data[val > x, .N, by = grp]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  71.07    0.03   73.75
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to count the number of values which exceed a threshold for each `grp` and for each threshold given in `filter`.

This can be solved using `non-equi joins` which became available with `data.table` version v1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016).

Here are two variants. The first one simply counts all values above each threshold which means that some values are compared and counted multiple times.

The second variant tries to avoid the multiple compares and counts the values within each interval and computes a cumulative sum in a second step.

As a benchmark shows the speedup is rather small.

#### Variant 1

```
aggregated <- data[CJ(grp = unique(grp), lb = filter), 
                   on = .(grp, val > lb), .N, by = .EACHI]
dcast(aggregated, grp ~ val)
```

> ```
>    grp  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> 1:   a 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  0
> 2:   b 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  0
> 3:   c 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  0
> 4:   d 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  0
> ```

Note that the column headers denote  threshold values.

#### Variant 2

```
fl <- CJ(grp = unique(data$grp), lower = filter)[
  , upper := shift(lower, type = "lead", fill = Inf)][]
tmp <- data[fl, on = .(grp, val > lower, val <= upper), .N, by = .EACHI ][
  order(-val), .(val, N = cumsum(N)), by = grp][]
dcast(tmp, grp ~ val)
```

> ```
>    grp  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> 1:   a 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  0
> 2:   b 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  0
> 3:   c 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  0
> 4:   d 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  0
> ```

#### Benchmark

Unfortunately, I could not get the solutions provided by [Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317993/3817004) and [Eddi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21318182/3817004) to work with the actual data.table version 1.10.5. So, this benchmark just compares the two *non-equi join* variants using Eddi's benchmark data.

```
# create benchmark data
N = 2e6
set.seed(123L)
data = data.table(val = runif(N, 1, N), grp = sample(letters, N, T))
filter = seq(0, N, by = N/200)

# define check function
my_check <- function(values) {
  all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) identical(values[[1]], x)))
}

#run benchmark
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  nej1 = {
    aggregated <- data[CJ(grp = unique(grp), lb = filter), on = .(grp, val > lb), .N, by = .EACHI]
    dcast(aggregated, grp ~ val, value.var = "N")
  },
  nej2 =
  {
    fl <- CJ(grp = unique(data$grp), lower = filter)[, upper := shift(lower, type = "lead", fill = Inf)][]
    tmp <- data[fl, on = .(grp, val > lower, val <= upper), .N, by = .EACHI ][
      order(-val), .(val, N = cumsum(N)), by = grp][]
    dcast(tmp, grp ~ val, value.var = "N")
  },
  check = my_check,
  times = 20L
)
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
>  nej1 358.6231 368.8033 389.6501 378.1158 391.8690 556.3323    20   b
>  nej2 347.6321 360.4038 365.2218 366.9392 370.1697 382.8185    20  a
> ```

The speed advantage of variant 2 is less than 5 per cent. This may vary if a computationally more intensive aggregation function is used.